# Use zone.js inside node (not angular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, zone.js

I would like to use zone.js in my node app.

Although I have found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563213/using-zone-js-hooks-in-node) in which is described how to do this, I still get `zone` is not defined error

For example. I also found an examples likt this

```
let zone = require('zone');

zone.run(function () {
    zone.inTheZone = true;

   setTimeout(function () {
       console.log('in the zone: ' + !!zone.inTheZone);
   }, 0);
});
```

Which gives the same error, but I inspected the `zone` object, I noticed that it returns an object like this

```
{
    enable: function() { .. }
}
```

So I guess that the zone API changed. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try zone-node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things:

1. require `zone.js` instead of `zone`
2. use `Zone.current` to get reference to the current zone

This works:

```
const zone = require('zone.js');

Zone.current.run(function () {
    zone.inTheZone = true;

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('in the zone: ' + !!zone.inTheZone);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: way too broad question) you might find [this doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F5Ug0jcrm031vhSMJEOgp1l-Is-Vf0UCNDY-LsQtAIY/edit#heading=h.e5oec3xkpw1r) very useful

Comment: Great doc, thnx! but with `zone` I didn't mean `zone.js` but your const in your example. I guess its a reference to that zone

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri, yeah, you actually don't need to save `require('zone.js')` to any variable since you always have reference to the current zone with `Zone.current` or `with Zone.current.fork` returns a reference to the zone.